# Changing command type from text to stored procedure stops datareader running

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have a C# web forms project built in VS2010 and I would like to move from using hard coded SQL queries to stored procedures to interrogate my SQL Server database so i can use parameters.

The code I am having difficulty with reads in data from the database using an sql data reader, and creates a comma separated string that i use for a list of available values for a textbox using jquery autocomplete.

This works fine when using hard coded sql but when i try and change this to a stored procedure and add parameters the textbox has no values available. When I debug this i can see that the code inside the `while (reader.Read())` is not getting run. Meaning the code to create the comma separated string is not being run.

**Using hard coded SQL (this works)**

```
string mySQLQuery = "SELECT col1 from table1"
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, myConnection))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //code to create comma separated string
        }
    }
}
```

**Converted to using stored procedure (this doesn't work)**

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("storedProcedureName", myConnection))
{
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value1;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value2;

    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //code to create comma separated string
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What SQL Server You are using? Ms Sql, Oracle, Informix?

Comment: It's all right with your code.

Comment: Wrap the code in try/catch. Sql exceptions are usually descriptive enough to let you know what is going on.

Comment: @goodeinstein, what a comment? *What SQL Server You are using?*

Comment: @Rahul what is wrong in this question?

Comment: @goodeinstein, it's totally wrong *What SQL Server You are using? Ms Sql, Oracle, Informix?* .. do you think Oracle is part of Sql Server? moreover, OP has already tagged with `SQL Server`

Comment: @Rahul Ok, now i can see. What database You are using? This is good question, right?

Comment: Can you post your stored procedure `storedProcedureName` code here

Comment: I have tested executing the stored procedure in SSMS and it runs fine, unfortunately I cannot post the code as it contains confidential business logic.

Comment: I have tried wrapping the code in a try/catch but it doesnt throw an exception so i don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort this out, the issue was to do with the values of parameters being passed to the stored procedure which is included in code that I didnt include.

The values were being passed to the stored procedure but the procedure was not returning any values which is why it appeared like the `while(myreader.read())` line was being skipped.

The code now works fine, thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the name of param should by without @ but it is depends of database. I using without "@" to MSSQL and it works

I use @ prefix only in sql command.

```
"Select * from table where name = @name"
```

Change this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value1;
```

to this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value1;
```

for param2 is the same

Comment: See help from ms:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` are MSSQL specific. The `@` symbol is needed.

Comment: No, that's not an issue at all.